# fullpage.js : use 2 differents animation on direction=up / direction=down

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, animate.css

So I'm using fullpage.js and animate.css, but right not I'm only able to make the animations work one time when going down. I'd like to make the reverse animation or whatever animation on going up or down again. basicly I want the animations to go off everytime I enter a section and not just one time!

I'm kinda new with this so I need a little help thanks!

```
            //animation section1 AFTERLOAD
            'afterLoad': function(anchorLink, index){
                var $AnimPage1 = $('#section1 .is-animated');

                if(index == 1){
                    $AnimPage1.addClass('animated slideInDown');
                }
            },

            //animation section ONLEAVE
            'onLeave': function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                var $AnimPage1 = $('#section1 .is-animated');
                var $AnimPage2 = $('#section2 .is-animated');
                var $AnimPage3 = $('#section3 .is-animated');
                var $AnimPage4 = $('#section4 .is-animated');
                var $AnimPage5 = $('#section5 .is-animated');

                if (index == 1 && direction == 'down'){
                    $AnimPage2.addClass('animated slideInUp');
                }
                if (index == 2 && direction == 'down'){
                    $AnimPage3.addClass('animated slideInUp');
                }
                if (index == 3 && direction == 'down'){
                    $AnimPage4.addClass('animated slideInUp');
                }
                if (index == 4 && direction == 'down'){
                    $AnimPage5.addClass('animated slideInUp');
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [animate.css docs](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage) regarding how to animate things multiple times:

```
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});


$('#yourElement').animateCss('bounce');
```